# Why can't I see the render result of fire and smoke simulation?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, fluid-simulation

I'm doing some fire and smoke simulation, and I can see the result in *Solid Mode*, but not in *Render Preview*, and I can't explain why.

I have no material on the domain because I was never told to do so in the tutorial I follow.

Blender version is 3.1.2, and graphic card is a GTX 1650 over an Intel i5-9400f.

Using Cycles.

[image: Solid Mode]

[image: Render Preview]

Comment: Do you have a material on the smoke domain? A volumetric material?

Comment: as you can see on the comments of Gordon you didn't provide enough information for your question. So please edit your question and improve it by showing us all relevant settings/details. Thanks. I would be quick with that before your question gets closed....

Comment: This is either because of a bad or missing domain material, or because you’re using an old version of blender that had a bug in it where volumetrics would not be visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edit confirms the issue: you have no material.

Now if you are following a tutorial that shows you a renderable result, either you missed the part where they show how to get the material, or it might be - debatably - not that good of a tutorial.

The simplest and easy way to get a functional material from a fire simulation, is simply to plug a Principled Volume shader to your domain's volume material output, and set the Blackbody Intensity value to 1:

[image: material demo]

Comment: That was it bro, thank you so much. I don't know how I could know that by myself D: